# ftp port in aws still closed after update security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, ftp, port

I went to security group and add the rule for tcp 21

[image]

But when use this [**tool**](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) to check the port, still say is closed.

[image]

I know the tool works, because if I remove the line for http, then say port 80 is closed.

So why even when add the port to the security group still appear as closed?

**EDIT**: The FileZila server is running but still the port say is close on the public ip.  Using FileZila client direct on the amazon machine I can connect to localhost. But from outside using the public ip I cant.

using netstats -an

[image]

and netstats -ab

```
TCP    [::]:21                myserver:0         LISTENING
[FileZilla Server.exe]

TCP    0.0.0.0:21             myserver:0         LISTENING
[FileZilla Server.exe]
```

Comment: Do you have an application listening on port 21? What happens if you try to connect from the command line on your instance to the FTP server?

Comment: @Tim I can connect to ftp if using localhost. But cant connect using public ip. Check edit.

Comment: I suspect your FTP server is configured incorrectly, but I'm not sure quite how.

Answer (score 3):

A service must be running on the port for it to be open. Start your FTP server.

Comment: Thanks Michael, the FileZilla server is running but still show the port is closed. Please check the edit.